# How to disable particular click event of a formArray after one click in each formArray element in angular 12?

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

```html
<div formArrayName="addGrp">
    <div id="ifElse_block" class="create-rules-section" *ngFor="let grp of addGrp().controls; let k=index" [formGroupName]="k">
        <div formGroupName="ifBlockRule" class="ifBlockRule">
             <!-- how disable below button after one click in each array element-->
             <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" class="addGrpCond" (click)="ifBlockAddGrpCondition(k)" [disabled]="addGrpBtnclicked" title="Add group condition">
             <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
             </button>
             <!-- how disable above button after one click in each array element-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to disable the button mentioned in commented lines after one click in array element? I am new to angular.

Comment: Can you also share the typescript part of your code?

Comment: I cant share whole code but :

Comment: rule_object: this.fb.group({ addGrp: this.fb.array([]),})
addGrp(): FormArray {return this.createRuleForm.get("rule_object.addGrp") as FormArray;}
newGrp(): FormGroup { return this.fb.group({ ifBlockRule: ''}) }
addGrpElements() {this.addGrp().push(this.newGrp());}
removeGrp(k: number) {this.addGrp().removeAt(k);}
ifBlockAddGrpCondition(k: number) {need something here}